# How to receive image over a socket in Dart

Tags: flutter, sockets, dart, socket.io, client

I am not able to retrive file through sockets, it divides the byte array if data increases than a certain length. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please show, in code, a minimal reproducible example. You are likely only listening to the first 'chunk' of data, rather than the whole stream of chunks.

Comment: When listening through sockets when the data increases certain length it breaks into chunks of byte arrays. For data other than image I was using this piece of code dataReceived += (String.fromCharCodes(data)).trim();
          if (dataReceived[dataReceived.length - 1] == ']') {

            List parsed = jsonDecode(dataReceived);

But for listening to image of from different arrays is a problem

Comment: Check out: https://pub.dev/documentation/buffer/latest/buffer/ByteDataWriter-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Sockets i/o (and especially when using UDP) is a low level communication protocol that gives you a lot of power but also requires you to solve problems like packets getting chopped up, getting dropped or arriving out of order.  You can figure that all out yourself, but you may also want to look at using a package like [socket.io-client-dart](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) that takes care of all those edge cases.